# OpenMP Memory Allocation

Tags: memory-management, parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, intel-fortran

I have a question about openMP memory allocation (language: Intel Fortran). I wrote a program and tested it with two different machines. It contains an openMP-parallelized DO LOOP, which is basically at the heart of the program and takes most of the computational time.

The first machine specs are Intel Xeon X5690 (2 processors, 2x6 cores, 3.47 GHz, 40 Gb). The program ran smoothly in 34m. The second one is (or at least should be) way much more performing in terms of specs (Intel Xeon E5, 28 cores and all that jazz). However, surprisingly enough, the program ran in about 3h30m hours on this second workstation. I was then advised to profile it with CrayPat and the verdict was that the time required to allocate, deallocate and free memory took 80% of the computational time because some functions called inside the DO LOOP had to allocate some (not too large) arrays. I then decided to rewrite the program avoiding almost all of these allocations (I just allocated all the variables once before the beginning of the DO LOOP). I repeated the same test and I got that the first machine took 3h30m to run the whole program and the second machine about 4h30m.

What is most suprising is that if I run the program with just one thread (first version, not the one modified), the second machine is faster than the first (around 3h30m vs 2h50m)!

It might be relevant to add that the program contains quad precision complex operations and that no optimization options are applied (default by Intel Fortran).

I'm wondering why such a huge discrepancy arises and what would you recommend me to do to speed up the program on the second machine? It seems clear that OpenMP in the second machine deals with memory in a "different" way from what I expected.

Comment: I'm confused by the first "ran smoothly in 34m" when all the other times are multiple hours.  Typo?

Comment: Dear timday! No typos 34 minutes. I ran the same program today once more and still got the same time. I obviously got the same data for all the tests. The only thing that I changed is the makefile. The first workstation runs on windowd while the second in a linux environment.

Comment: Dear Mark, system_clock. I measured the wall-clock time, not the cpu time. I'm sure about the correctness of the time because I was monitoring the computations all the time. Honestly, I'm not sure about what the cpu_time refers to in case of parallel threads so I avoided it. By the way, the number of threads is the same (12) in both computations.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] to get more attention.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. It was due to the fact that in a subroutine I had all complex operations whereas if all the other subroutines and main programs I used a two-element array for every complex number. By changing the two element array into a couple of scalars, I got that the time taken to compute the solution was reduced to 26m (vs 34m) on the first machine and 25m (vs around 4h30m) on the second machine. Undoubtedly, using the COMPLEX type instead of a couple of arryas for the whole program could be a good resolution for the future.
 Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Well, OpenMP does not have anything to do with memory allocation.

Maybe the way you are allocating memory translates into false sharing problems.

Also it is not all that surprising to me to find that the 28 cores machine is slower than the 12 cores machine.

If you have many cores and you are allocating a lot of memory, depending on the way you do it and the data decomposition being used, you may generate a lot of communication between cores. The more cores you have, the more traffic you generate. Specially if you do not properly align memory allocations to avoid [cache thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29).

Allocating all the variables before entering the loop can also slow down your program because allocation is done completely serial instead being parallelized. Current dynamic memory implementations use locks to protect memory allocations, but they also keep internal memory pools to avoid constantly entering into kernel mode, allowing better concurrent access, diminishing contention.

My general recommendation in order to have better use of the 28 core machine is to properly parallelize memory allocation inside the DO LOOP and properly partition the data. Threads have to interfere as little as possible. Based on your post, that seems the bottleneck of the program.